# Django: Ajax function is not triggered when I submit the form

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I try to make a basic chat app that will show the message sent without the page refreshing, but for some reason I can't make that javascript running.

**html**

```
<form id="chat-form" method="POST" action="/chat/{{ sender.id }}{{ receiver.id }}/post/"> {% csrf_token %}
<div id="chat-bottom" class="input-group">
    <input id="textbox_message" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your message" name="textbox_message">    
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input id="send" class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit" value="Send" name="btn_send"/>
    </span>
</div>
```

**ajax**

```
$('#chat-form').on('submit', function(event){
event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url : '/chat/{{ sender.id }}{{ receiver.id }}/post/',
        type : 'POST',
        data : { msg : $('#textbox_message').val() },
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(json){
            $('#textbox_message').val('');//clear the chat message box
            $('#msg-list').append('<li class="text-right list-group-item">' + json.message + '</li>');// append the new message to the list
            var chatlist = document.getElementById('msg-list-div');
            chatlist.scrollTop = chatlist.scrollHeight;//scroll down after the message is send
        }
        error: function(){
            alert("Error while sending the message");
        }
    });
});
```

**views.py**

```
def post_message(request, sender, receiver):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if ('textbox_message' in request.POST) and request.POST['textbox_message'].strip():
            message = request.POST['textbox_message']

            Inbox.send_message(request.user, User.objects.get(id = receiver), message)

            return JsonResponse({ 'message': message})

    return HttpResponse("Deal with this later")
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<sender>\d+)(?P<receiver>\d+)/$', views.index),
    url(r'^(?P<sender>\d+)(?P<receiver>\d+)/post/$', views.post_message),
]
```

**The question is:** why the Ajax is not triggered (it doesn't enter neither the success nor the error calls) and how can I make it work?

*Just a side note*: This is my first time using Ajax and I'm fairly new to Django too, but I am willing to learn and receive any extra advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it going in your on submit function ? Try putting a console.log and see if it is going in that function.

Comment: MF, there are few things you need to be careful about.. If you have your javascript code outside HTML, the elements in {{ }} will no be rendered.. Also, as you are posting data with ``'/chat/{{ sender.id }}{{ receiver.id }}/post/' ``, how do you expect your regex interpreter to know if 123456 is 123 456 or 1234 56. Add a / between the URL parameters. you have a ``/chat/``, are these app's urls? Have you at any moment rerouted the requests coming to ``/chat/`` to this url.py?

Comment: @bobleujr the javascript is placed inside the html template. `/chat/` is the path to the chat application urls.py and I don't think I understand what you mean by rerouting the requests coming to `/chat/`. Also, thanks for the remark regarding the "/", I didn't thought about that.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki no it doesn't. I receive the JsonResponse in the browser as if the ajax (or the whole javascript event) isn't even there